# Не принимается почта "извне"

Tags: debian, postfix

Пытаясь сделать свою простенькую личную почту на сервере.

Установил связку **Postfix+Dovecot** по этой статье:
[link text](http://blog.xelfaer.ru/?p=492)

Проблема следующая: локально почта пересылается-принимается, вообще без проблем. Подключаюсь клиентом (Thunderbird) к ящику - с него куда угодно отправляются (и доходят) письма. На мой же ящик письма "извне" (с яндекса/yahoo) не приходят, пишут, что невозможно доставить.

А/MX записи домена прикручены к серверу, порты открыты.

Каким образом заставить почтовик принимать письма от других серверов? Чего прописать в конфигах?

Answer (score 1):

если, как вы пишете, mx-записи настроены корректно, то:

1. проверьте, действительно ли программа *postfix* слушает 25-й порт на внешнем интерфейсе. для этого из внешнего мира попробуйте тем же *telnet*-ом подключиться на 25-й порт своего сервера (пример ответа приведён для сервера `mx.yandex.ru`):

   ```
   $ telnet ваш-сервер 25
   Trying 77.88.21.89...
   Connected to mx.yandex.ru.
   Escape character is '^]'.
   220 mxfront5o.mail.yandex.net (Want to use Yandex.Mail for your domain? Visit http://pdd.yandex.ru)
   ```
2. если слушает, то следует смотреть логи программы *postfix* (скорее всего, `/var/log/mail`) и уже на основании того, что туда попадает при попытке отправить письмо с внешного мира на ваш адрес, делать какие-то выводы о том, что уже у вас «не так» в конфигурации.

Comment: +1 - нужно смотреть коды ошибок и логи. Без них ничего конкретного не скажешь. Гипотетически могу предположить, что не созданы пользователи на сервере, поэтому почта и не может быть доставлена - некому ее доставлять.... хотя при таком раскладе она должна копией валиться в ящик postmaster@...

Дополнительно хочу сказать, что стоит попробовать exim, а если планируете сидеть на текущей связки - очень полезно поставить roundcube web-клиент в целях хотя бы отладки. очень удобно!